# LED lights strip quickly flashes and goes off

Tags: electrical, led

I've just recently constructed some cut to size RGB LED strips to fit around some shelves using T & L connectors.

When I finished and connected the 12v adapter to turn them on, all the LEDs quickly flash once and then they all go out again and don't come back on.  It's seems that all the strips are connected correctly so can't be a connection issue as all the light flash.

Just out of curiosity I removed that last strip that connected directly to the the power supply and turned on the power to see if that worked on it own. The same issue happened.

When I first received this 5m roll of LEDs I checked them with the power supply supplied and it all worked fine.

Any idea what might be stalling the lights staying on?

Comment: It sounds like the adapter has a problem. Can you measure the output voltage of the adapter to see if it is about 12 VDC?

Comment: If there is a short somewhere, they could flash on until the power supply reaches an over-current condition and cuts out.  Is there a way to bypass each connection and test portions of the LEDs rather than the whole install?

Answer (score 1):

2 amps isn’t gonna do it. 
Had same trouble. 
With arrows aligned, got a one time flash, then nothing.

They were cheap so could be anything. 
Bad battery in remote, crap connectors, broken led wires, thermo failsafe in module( kinda right)....etc.
Most would chocked it up to “you get what you pay for” and tossed them in trash and moved on with a healthy productive life.

But by then it was personal.
Was lucky enough to have bought 2 of them(10m
rbg), so was able to switch out parts and after lot of google and YouTube, learned that you need about 5-8 amps to make this work.

It was shutting down because of a power problem, but it wasn’t because it was over powered, it was cause I wasn’t giving min required workings amps.

Went from 12v2a to 12/5a and “let there be light”, all parts working.

Ps
Long span wattage drop is a thing. Don’t try to amp your way through it. Fire is not good indoor mood lighting. 
Take time to research the safe way and don’t die